# Seam method not found

Tags: java, seam

I am using the seam framework and when I render `.xhtml` file (which contains `stManagerImpl`) it should create an instanse of `stManagerImpl`. But it gives me an exception:

```
javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: Method not found:
    com.student.stManagerImpl@1b41711.showForm(java.lang.Long)
```

Even before calling `@begin` annotated function.

Where can be attached the `showForm((java.lang.Long)` method to `stManagerImpl`

Thanks

Comment: have there any config file wich tells to Seam that call to myfunction() before creating instance of this bean?

Comment: Looks like you don't have that method defined. Maybe you defined a similar one using `long` instead of `java.lang.Long`?